# Broken Bootstrap Navbar Links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

On mobile (iOS using Safari and Google Chrome), lightly tapping without clicking a navbar item changes its color from gray to black (the behavior you get with `:hover` on desktop). This only happens with some of the items, however, and only if `navbar-fixed-top` is used. After searching in vain, I found a [related issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1768#issuecomment-15429813), but unfortunately it was not addressed.

Removing the padding is not an option since doing so will render certain elements invisible. I would also like to avoid using `navbar-static-top`.

How should I go about this?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <style>
      body {
        padding-top:50px;
      }
    </style>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Site</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="">Hover Broken #1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Hover Broken #2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Hover OK</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Hover OK</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Hover Broken #3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container" style="padding-top:25px;">
      <div class="row" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;">
        <div class="pull-right">
          <label>
            <div style="display:inline-block">Option:&nbsp;</div>
            <div style="display:inline-block">
              <select class="btn-sm btn-default" id="page_rows" style="cursor: pointer">
                <option value="">1</option>
                <option value="">2</option>
                <option value="">3</option>
                <option value="">4</option>
                <option value="">5</option>      
              </select>
            </div>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
          <a data-toggle="tab" href=""><span class="badge">Count</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="table-responsive text-center">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Column</th>
              <th>Column</th>
              <th>Column</th>
              <th>Column</th>
              <th>Column</th>
              <th>Column</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/55acd3ex/

Comment: How're you using hover in a touchscreen?

Comment: Come to think of it, you're absolutely right. I suppose I meant "lightly tapping without clicking". Doing so changes the color of the link from gray to black for some items only, wheareas on desktop it is the consistent behavior you get with `:hover`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is an [official "answer"](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-sticky-hover-mobile) after all:

> Even though real hovering isn't possible on most touchscreens, most
>   mobile browsers emulate hovering support and make `:hover` "sticky". In
>   other words, `:hover` styles start applying after tapping an element and
>   only stop applying after the user taps some other element. This can
>   cause Bootstrap's `:hover` states to become undesirably "stuck" on such
>   browsers. Some mobile browsers also make `:focus` similarly sticky.
>   There is currently no simple workaround for these issues other than
>   removing such styles entirely.

Answer (score 0):

`:hover` wouldn't work on a mobile as your screen im guessing would have to sense when the users finger is hovering over the screen before the tapped on screen and i don't think any mobile phone currently has such magic :)

as for the `navbar-fixed-top` just remove it and everything should be ok

Comment: That sadly makes perfect sense it's almost embarrassing. Anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41831995/broken-bootstrap-navbar-links#comment70868946_41831995